# jquery plugin "DROP-DOWN LIST" add fontawesome icons

Tags: jquery, plugins, drop-down-menu, font-awesome

I use this nice jQuery plugin (**SIMPLE EFFECTS FOR DROP-DOWN LISTS**)

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/29/simple-effects-for-drop-down-lists/

How can I add a new icon from FontAwesome, keeping at the same time the format in the following screen shot?

[image]

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the example you have to change the font used from `iconmoon` to `fontawesome` web fonts.

The iconmoon web fonts have a very small list of supported icons.

Code:

```
.cd-dropdown span[class^="icon-"]:before, 
.cd-dropdown span[class*=" icon-"]:before {
    font-family: 'fontawesome' !important;
}
```

After doing that the styles will be matained and you can use all yout icons.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/k4FWN/

Comment: Thank you! It works! From this link you get the codes. 
http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/
We must not forget to include fontawesome fonts in css